# automatic scrolling in code for PDF using React Native and react-native-pdf

Tags: react-native, pdf, scrollview

I'm a bit new to React Native programming, and I'm working on implementing an autoscroll feature for PDFs. For example, in some cases, I want to automatically scroll a PDF down x pages and then scroll at a desired speed. I followed this tutorial here [here](https://medium.com/4thought-studios/react-native-auto-scrolling-for-fun-and-profit-fabadc3702e7) which works for just normal data, but when I used a  object from react-native-pdf, it does not seem to scroll anymore. I'm wrapping the PDF object inside a ScrollView and can confirm that the scrolling code is being called. Can anyone suggest a solution or explain why this does not work with the PDF? Thanks so much!

I've also attached my code below if that helps. Currently, the PDF displays but is not autoscrolling at all.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Dimensions, View, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';

export default class PDFScroll extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPosition: 0,
        };
        this.scrolling = this.scrolling.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.activeInterval = setInterval(this.scrolling, 100);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.activeInterval);
    }

    scrolling() {
        position = this.state.currentPosition + 50;
        this.pdf.scrollTo({ x: position, animated: true });
        // After position passes this value, snaps back to beginning
        let maxOffset = 2000;
        // Set animation to repeat at end of scroll
        if (this.state.currentPosition > maxOffset) {
             this.pdf.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: false })
             this.setState({ currentPosition: 0 });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ currentPosition: position });
        }

    }

    render() {
        const source = {
            uri: 'http://samples.leanpub.com/thereactnativebook-sample.pdf',
            cache: true,
        };

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView
                style={styles.scrollview}
                horizontal={false}
                bounces={true}
                ref={(ref) => this.pdf = ref}
            >
                {
                    <Pdf
                        source={source}
                        onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
                            console.log(`number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
                        }}
                        onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {
                            console.log(`current page: ${page}`);
                        }}
                        onError={error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        }}
                        onPressLink={uri => {
                            console.log(`Link presse: ${uri}`);
                        }}
                        style={styles.pdf}
                    />
                }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 25,
    },
    pdf: {
        flex: 1,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    },
});
```